# ari package - use of SSML for Amazon Polly

Tags: r

I have tried to figure out how to use SSML in the ari-package when using Amazon Polly to read the texts.

Here is an example that does not work. Both with and without `<speak>`

```
slides <- system.file("test", c("mab2.png", "mab1.png"),
                      package = "ari")
sentences <- c("Welcome to my very <s> interesting lecture.",
               "<speak>Here are some fantastic <s> equations I came up with.</speak>")
ari_spin(slides, sentences, voice = "Brian", output = "Videos/slides_test_test.mp4")
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you so much.

Bernd